# Jenkins 2 Pipelines: Is it possible to customize the stage text content in the view?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

By default I see the stage duration in ms or sec. Is it possible to customize this text? It would help provide visual clues to each stage run.
I couldn't find any reference in the docs...

Answer (score 2):

Today is not possible to customize this, there is an [open issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26522) in the Jenkins tracker in order to make it possible.

Hope that is what you described.